# List of SharePoint Internet websites

Tags: 2010, public-website, internet

We are evaluating SharePoint 2010 for our internet websites and we need a list of existing websites to evaluate SharePoint. I am aware of case studies from Microsoft but they are pretty old.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out this comprehensive list at WSS Demo, http://www.wssdemo.com/livepivot/

Comment: Wow! Thats an awesome link.

Comment: wssdemo's list is automatically generated by a webcrawler. It's pretty nifty.

Comment: It's always been my favorite, and that fancy Silverlight (I presume) presentation just takes the cake!

Comment: This link is outdated, Ian Morrish has moved on from there and no longer supports wssdemo.com, it seems.

Answer (score 4):

I think http://www.topsharepoint.com/ has a good list.